# How to split string in pasteboard and paste to different inputbox for every splitted string?

Tags: ios, swift

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXSg0.png) I'm new to Swift here. I have form with rows of textfield input as shown in the picture. Is there a way to split the string in the pasteboard before using the default paste action to and paste it accordingly to the rows of input.

```
    let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
    let pasteboardval = pasteboard.string

    _ = pasteboardval?.split(separator: "\n")
```

I tried splitting the string in the pasteboard but how do I make sure when user execute the default paste function it will paste it the way I want it to be.

Thousand apologies if its confusing, I'm still new here.

Comment: Add IBOutlet collection for all these textFields and insert text using loop.

Comment: If you are gonna ask question without any code, you will get answers without any code. Please include the code which you have tried

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @AmirKhan. I just editted my question, hope its clearer

Comment: @CerlinBoss, thanks sir, edited my question, hope its clearer

Comment: `pasteboardval?.split(separator: "\n")` returns Array ?

Comment: yes sir, it returns Array, so it is possible to customize the default paste action or do I need to create a button to paste it instead?

Comment: @DesmondWong got your point. Don't call me Sir brother :)

Comment: Have you created IBOutlet for these Textfields?

Comment: yes I did @AmirKhan

Comment: ok let me do this.

Comment: @DesmondWong check my answer below.

Comment: Any update here?

Comment: Already understood the implementation concept. Thx for the help @AmirKhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation

1) Create a custom textField class

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    var customPasteDelegate: PasteDelegate!

    override func paste(_ sender: Any?) {
        customPasteDelegate.handlePaste()
    }
}
```

2) Create a protocol to handle paste operation

```
protocol PasteDelegate {
    func handlePaste()
}
```

3) Group the uitextfields in an array and set delegate

```
@IBOutlet var textFields: [CustomTextField]!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    for textField in textFields {
        textField.customPasteDelegate = self
    }
}
```

4) Implement handlePaste method in your controller

```
func handlePaste() {
    if let pasteString = UIPasteboard.general.string {
        let splitArray = pasteString.split(separator: "\n")

        for (index, val) in splitArray.enumerated() {
            textFieldsArray[index].text = String(val)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove each IBOutlet of textFields and add `IBOutlet collection` of TextFields -

```
@IBOutlet var txtInputFields: [UITextField]!
```

**Now time to paste into textFields -**

```
let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
let pasteboardval = pasteboard.string

let inputs = pasteboardval?.split(separator: "\n")

if let inputArray = inputs {

    for i in 0..<inputArray.count {

        if i < txtInputFields.count {

            txtInputFields[i].text = "\(inputArray[i])"
        }

    }
}
```